# How hard would it be to upgrade from the basic ubuntu openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-autopilot

How hard would it be to upgrade from the basic ubuntu openstack 10 server 10vms..

to the same 10 servers, but running 25 to 50 vms ?

What would i need to do and what extra would i need to purchase license wise.